# Filtering array of strings of NSManagedObject

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsset

I have NSManagedObject class like this

```
class Company: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name:    String
    @NSManaged var kind:    String
    @NSManaged var tags:    NSSet?
}
```

where "tags" contains array of strings (not NSManagedObjects). I'm trying to filter it like this:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Company")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY %@ in tags", tag)
request.fetchBatchSize = 20
let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```

but it didn't work. I also tried these possibilities:

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY tags CONTAINS %@", tag)
NSPredicate(format: "ANY tags.allObjects CONTAINS %@", tag)
```

Comment: `tags` is declares as `NSSet?`, but you say that it contains an *array*. – And if the value of `tags` is not managed objects, then why is it declared as `@NSManaged` ?

Comment: `NSSet` has `allObjects` property, which is an array. I couldn't use `NSManagedObject` properties without adding `@NSManaged`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have your predicate format incorrect.

Try:

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY %@ in %@", tag, tags)
```

Read here for corresponding [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Comment: Ok if you think so then good for you. But you did not. That you think you have indicates how little you understand about the code that you are attempting to write.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to search for ((all companies)) that have a specific tag in its "tags" property.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time in searching, the only solution I found is to change the type of `tags` to `String`, and filter it like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "ANY tags CONTAINS[CD] %@", tag)
```

It seems that it is not possible to filter `NSSet` properties of `NSManagedObject`